How to get the tables of workbook sheets from tableau server
I have to fetch some tableau server data.
I want a list of tableau workbook sheets and the tables those sheets have.
I also need type of chart (pie or bar etc.) used to represent the table data in the sheets.
Earlier I was using Tableau Server Client but I found that I can get only till workbook dashboards through that and not the sheets.
So now, I have used Metadata API to get the sheets because Tableau Server Client does not offer that functionality.
Here is my code -

# Authentication and server connection
tableau_auth = TSC.TableauAuth(username, password, site_id=siteName)
server = TSC.Server(
    tableau_server_url, use_server_version=True, http_options={"verify": False}
)

with server.auth.sign_in(tableau_auth):
    # Define the GraphQL query
    query = """
    query workbooks {
      workbooks {
        sheets {
          name
        }
      }
    }
    """

    # Execute the query and get results
    resp = server.metadata.query(query)
    print(resp)

I have two questions-

How to get the table these sheets store.

How to get the type of chart (pie or bar etc.) used to represent the table data in the sheets.


So, if you can help with any of these, please help, I am really stuck here.

If you're trying to get the raw data from the sheet, check out this post grabbing Tableau crosstab export via the API, otherwise when you say "Table" do you mean the datasource that is connected to Tableau?

Hi @MUFF.
Yes, the datasources. Is it possible to get sheets specific datasources ?

I am using "upstreamdatasources{ name}"
But I think it is returning all the datasources associated with the parent workbook instead of just the sheet.

I don't know how specifically get the DS used in the sheet but as a workaround, if you export to crosstab and you know the mapping of your fields to their respective datasources, you can get the info you need. I will continue to look into grabbing the sheet specific DS but not sure it's possible as technically every sheet has access to the datasources you brought into the workbook.

Okay, thanks for your efforts :).
BTW, do you know if there is any way to get calculated fields of a table?
I mean I used to think calculated field belong to datasource, but I am told to get a list of tables with its field and logic if it's a calculated field.
Do you have any idea how to do this, not through server but through api or metadata queries.
